# Retrieve all data from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

ANDROID: I have a Firebase database like this.[image: phoot]

In my app, I would like to compile an arraylist that displays all values from the `nameofEntry` [DESCRIBED BELOW]. By this I mean the "balso," the "nairboh" and so on.

I have the references:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference users = root.child("Users");
DatabaseReference childRef = users.child(userID);
DatabaseReference childRefNameNode = childRef.child(nameOfEntry);
childRefNameNode.child(nameOfEntry).setValue(nameOfEntry);
```

//FETCH DATA

```
childRefNameNode.child(nameOfEntry).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String valueFromDB = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("Jimit", valueFromDB);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

But this only fetches for one entry. How can I get more entries? [All of them]?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code snippet. You haven't used any ***for loop to step over your children.***

**EDIT:** *Also, update your database reference as:*

```
//Updated ref
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);*

    //add listener to updated ref
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                         //use the for loop here to step over each child and retrieve data                   
                         for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String valueFromDB = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            Log.i("Jimit", valueFromDB);
                        }


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: It doesn't unforunately

Comment: @augustalsina Check the edited answer and also note value event listener will only return snapshot of changed value.